# A restricted version of Riemann series theorem: rearrangements with alternating signs

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $(a_{n})$ is a conditionally convergent series in real field, then for any real number $\alpha$, there exists a rearrangement $(a_{k_{n}})$ of $(a_{n})$ such that for all even $n$, $a_{k_{n}} \geq 0$, for all odd $n$, $a_{k_{n}} \leq 0$, and $\sum a_{k_{n}} = \alpha$.

This problem boils down to the following problem: can every conditional real series be rearranged to an alternative convergent series. If this is solved, then apply the extensions of Riemann's theorem by [Sierpiński](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47589/how-to-rearrange-only-negative-part-of-a-conditionally-convergent-series-to-get), the original problem is done.

I appreciate any suggestion about this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without commenting on the content, problems worded as "Show that …" always sound to me like homework, unless there is some discussion of motivation.  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @LSpice you are right, this is a challenging problem present in "Supplements to the Exercises in Chapter 1-7 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis" by Prof. George M. Bergman, on page 41 problem 3.14:6.

Comment: You need to clarify that the series $\sum_n a_n$ *is* convergent. So the starting sentence should probably be "If $(a_n)$ is a convergent series which is not absolutely convergent ...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you prescribe in addition the sequence of signs of the rearranged series in the Riemann-Dini theorem to be alternating,  but note that any non-stationary binary sequence of signs does as well. More precisely:

> Let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb N} $ be an infinitesimal sequence of non-zero real
> numbers such that $\sum_{k\ge0}a^+_k=\sum_{k\ge0}a^-_k=+\infty$.
>
> Let $\epsilon\in \{-1,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ be a non-eventually constant
> sequence.
>
> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R \cup\{ \pm\infty\}$.
>
> Then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\mathbb N$ such that
> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\sigma(k)}=\alpha$$
> $$\text{sgn}\,a_{\sigma(k)}=\epsilon_k.$$

To this end: extract a subset  $S\subset\mathbb N$  such that $\sum_{k\in S}a_k$ is absolutely summable and $a_k$ are positive resp. negative for infinitely many $k\in S$ (therefore for infinitely many $k\in \mathbb N\setminus S$ as well, because of the assumption $\sum_{k\ge0}a^+_k=\sum_{k\ge0}a^-_k=+\infty$).

Then do the Riemann-Dini bijection $\tau:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N \setminus S$ relatively to the sequence $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb N\setminus S }$ and the number $\alpha-\sum_{k\in S}a_k$, namely $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\tau(k)}=\alpha-\sum_{k\in S}a_k.$$

Finally, insert the coefficients $\{a_k\}_{k\in S}$ in some order into the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\tau(k)}$, so as to get a rearrangement with the prescribed final sequence of signs $(\dagger)$. Since $\sum_{k\in S}a_k$ is absolutely summable, the order of the insertion does not affect the convergence and the value of the sum, which is $\alpha$ as wanted.

$(\dagger)$ This can easily be done, for the reason that any non eventually constant binary sequence contains any other non eventually constant binary sequence as a subsequence, in such a way that the complement is also non eventually constant.

Comment: Thanks so much for your generalization of my post, which does really deep my understanding about the conditionally convergent series. However, I still have difficulty to understand the dagger-symbolied sentence. How can we guarantee that the series after the insertion process is still convergent, and moreover, the corresponding convergent result is the sum of the two sub-series. I only know the fact that we can add finite zeros between successive terms of a convergent series still converges to the same value. Any sources (e.g., papers) are welcomed.

Comment: You're welcome. The $\dagger$ sentence is purely combinatoric. Given two binary sequences $(\epsilon_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ and $(\delta_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ in $\{-1,+1\}^{\mathbb N}$, both non eventually constant you can certainly find a copy of the latter within the former, that is a subsequence $\epsilon_{k_j}=\delta_j$ for all $j\in \mathbb N$, and you can do so in such a way that between  $\epsilon_{k_j}$ and $\epsilon_{k_{j+1}}$ there are at least one $-1$ and one $+1$, so that the "complement" string is not eventually constant.

Comment: You apply this to the initially prescribed sequence $\epsilon_k $ and to $\delta_j:=\text{sgn}\,a_{\tau(j)}$. This means that you can fill every place  $k_j$ with the coefficient $a_{\tau(j)}$ , that has the prescribed sign $a_{\tau(j)}=\epsilon_{k_j}$ at the place  $k_j$. The remaining places $\mathbb N\setminus \{k_j:j\in\mathbb N\}$ can be bijectively filled with the remaining coefficients $\{a_k\}_{k\in S}$ of the prescribed sign, because infinitely many of them must be $+1$ and infinitely many must be $-1$, and you do have enough of both among the $\{a_k\}_{k\in S}$.

Comment: Convergence: consider the final rearranged series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\sigma(k)}$. Any $n$-th partial sum of it is always a $m$-th partial sum of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\tau(k)}$ plus a $(n-m)$-th partial sum of some fixed rearrangement of $\sum_{k\in S}a_k$,  and by construction both $m$ and $n-m$ go to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $\sum_{k\in S}a_k$ does not depend on rearrangements because it is absolutely convergent,  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\sigma(k)}$ does converges to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\tau(k)}+\sum_{k\in S}a_k=\alpha$.

Comment: (By means of a more formal notation all the maps $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ I used may be constructed formally, but I thought an informal description could be easier to communicate)

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply, and please allow me some time to digest your saying.

Comment: Sure; feel free to ask for other details

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is yes. Let $a_{i_k}$ and $a_{j_k}$ be the even and odd terms respectively, ordered in increasing order of magnitude.

We will define four sequences; $b_n$ (indexed by $\mathbb Z_+$) which will be the desired rearranged sequence, a $-1, 1$ valued sequence $s_n$ (indexed by $\mathbb N$), which will be a “state/control” variable, and two sequences $P_n, M_n$ (indexed by $\mathbb N$) of natural numbers.

To this end, consider the following algorithm:

**Start algorithm.**

1. Set $P_0 = M_0 = 0$.
2. If $|a_{i_0}| \geq |a_{j_0}|$ , set $s_0 = 1$, else set $s_0 = -1$.
3. Assume $s_0, \dots, s_{n-1}; b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}, P_{n-1}, P_{n-1}$ have been defined,
4. Set $P_{n}$ (respectively $M_{n})$ to be the largest index $k$ such that $a_{i_m}$ (respectively $a_{j_m}$) has already been used for all $m < k$.
5. Do the following:

While $s_{n-1} = 1$, and $n$ is odd,

- If $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r >\alpha - a_{i_{P_{n}}}$, set $b_n = a_{j_{M_n}}$ and set $s_n = 1$; else set $b_n = a_{j_l}$ for any $l \geq M_n$ with $|a_{j_l}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{i_{P_n}}|$ and set $s_n = -1$.

While $s_{n-1} = 1$, and $n$ is even,

- If $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r >\alpha - a_{i_{P_{n}}}$, set $b_n = a_{i_l}$ for any $l$ with $|a_{i_l}|\leq \frac{1}{2} |a_{M_n}|$ and set $s_n = 1$; else set $b_n = a_{i_{P_n}}$ and set $s_n = -1$.

While $s_{n-1}= -1$, and $n$ is even,

- If $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r < \alpha - a_{i_{M_{n}}}$, set $b_n = a_{i_{P_n}}$ and set $s_n = -1$; else set $b_n = a_{i_l}$ for any $l \geq P_n$ with $|a_{i_l}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{j_{M_n}}|$ and set $s_n = 1$.

While $s_{n-1} = -1$, and $n$ is odd,

- If $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r < \alpha - a_{j_{M_{n}}}$, set $b_n = a_{j_l}$ for any $l$ with $|a_{j_l}|\leq \frac{1}{2} |a_{P_n}|$ and set $s_n = -1$; else set $b_n = a_{i_{M_n}}$ and set $s_n = 1$.

**End algorithm.**

I claim this algorithm exhausts all terms. Indeed it suffices to show that $b_n = a_{i_{P_n}}$ and $b_n = a_{j_{P_n}}$ infinitely often. We prove only the former, the proof for the latter being identical via symmetry.

Thus assume for contradiction that $b_k = a_{i_{P_k}}$ for only finitely many $k$, and let $K$ be the largest of these. Then the terms $b_n$ starting from $n = K+1$ are $a_{i_{M_n}}, a_{i_{l_n}}, a_{i_{M_{n+1}}}, a_{i_{l_{n+1}}}, \dots$, and further it is always the case that $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r >\alpha - a_{i_{P_{n}}}$ for even $n > K$.

But since $|a_{i_{l_n}}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{i_{M_n}}|$, and the sequence $\sum a_{j_k}$ diverges (to negative infinity), we must eventually have $\overset{n-1}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r < \alpha - a_{i_{P_{n}}}$, contradiction.

Finally, to see that $\sum b_n$ converges to $\alpha$, it suffices to note that by construction, once $s_n$ has switched values at least once, then from that point on $\overset{n}{\underset {i=1} {\sum}} b_r$ is no more than $2(|a_{P_n}| + |a_{M_n}|)$ away from $\alpha$, which goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: where are $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ used? and also seems your $(a_{i_{k}})$ and $(a_{j_{k}})$ are the positive and negative terms in their original order, right? So your comparison at step 2 should be the comparison of their absolute value, right? Sorry I did not go though completely and may misunderstand your points

Comment: Sorry $A_n$ and $B_n$ should read $P_n$ and $M_n$ respectively. Also yes. The lack of absolute values is a typo. Will correct it.

Comment: No worries, please allow me some time to digest your process

Comment: Sure no prob! Btw there is another edit - step 1 should read $P_0 = M_0 = 0$.